# Transit visa for Technical stop in Bangkok

Tags: visas

I am travelling from the UK to Australia and on leg 2 have a technical stop in Bangkok for 90mins. Do I need a visa for this stop, I am getting back on the same plane and flight number, my checked luggage will stay on board but ticket says I might need a visa. Grateful for advice

Comment: What is your nationality? Are you on a charter flight, and where does the wording "technical stop" come from?

Answer (score 2):

The website of [VisaGuide.World](https://visaguide.world/asia/thailand-visa/transit/) has:

> **Do I Need a Thailand Airport Transit Visa?**
>
> If you are transiting in a Thailand airport, you do not need an airport transit visa if:
>
> - Your connecting flight is in less than 12 hours
> - Your flight is booked on the same ticket
> - You do not leave the international airport transit area
> - You have the necessary documents for your final destination
>
> However, according to the International Air Transport Association’s (IATA) Timatic, this rule does not include Pakistan nationals or foreigners traveling through the following airlines: Angkor Air, Beijing Capital Airlines, Business Air, Cebu Pacific, Eaststar Jet, Golden Myanmar Airlines, Indigo, Jeju Air, Jet Asia Airways, Jetstar, Jetstar Pacific, Jin Air, JuneYao Airlines, Lao Central Airlines, Mandara Airlines, Norwegian Air, Okay Airways, Orient Thai Airlines, Regent Air, Scoot, Shandong Airlines, Shanghai Airlines, Shenzhen Airlines, Siberia Airlines, Sichuan Airlines, South East Asian Airlines, Spice Jet, Thai Smile Airlines, Tianjin Airlines, Trans Aero, Turkmenistan Airlines, T’way Airlines, Ural Airlines and VietJet Air.

---

Tracing this back to a Thai source, the website of [Thailand Visa](https://www.thailandevisas.com/visa-types/transit-visa/) is a bit more specific:

> **Is a Thailand Airport Transit Visa Required?**
>
> In the case of those flying into Don Mueang International Airport in Bangkok, an eVisa is required for transit for those who are flying with Thai Air Asia and Thai Air Asia X. For all others, you will not require a visa if your transit time is less than 12 hours.
>
> For those whose point of arrival into Thailand is Suvarnabhumi Airport, you will require an electronic Thailand visa for transit if you are traveling with
>
> - (similar list of airlines)
>
> For all other passengers who are in transit, you will require an eVisa for transit through Thailand if your total transit time exceeds 12 hours.
>
> Pakistani passengers are the exception to this rule as all Pakistani citizens wishing to transit through Thailand will require a visa to do so, regardless of the airline they are flying on or the length of the transit time.

Comment: For additional reference https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/